# XSL-FO 3 pages flow

Tags: xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I using XSLT and XML to create XSL-FO, from where to generate PDFs. The engine used is supporting only XSLT1.0.

I am trying to set up a layout that will be like this:

- First page will have a repeating table that can flow over 1 to 3 pages.
- Footer: - Page 1 will be some content - "footer01";
  - Page 2 will be different content - "footer02"
  - Page 3 and all the other pages will have different content - All Other Pages Footer"

The issue I am facing is setting up the flow, in order to met the following:

- when repeating table content (added on Page1) is displayed only on first page, then I need Page2 to be a blank page, and Page 3 and other pages to have any additional remaining  content;
- when repeating table content (added on Page1) is enough for two pages, it can go over Page1 and Page2, and any additional content will start with Page3. Footers will be different on Page1 on Page2 and all other pages starting with Page3. Page2 will no longer be blank
- if repeating table from Page1 is displayed on three pages, it can flow from Page1 to Page3 (with different footers as above), and any additional content will start with the next page - Page4, and Page2 will no longer be blank.

Is that even possible to achieve this? How will I need to set up the Page Sets/Layouts?  Thanks!

My simplified XSLFO I tried with, but is not meeting all above conditions:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="Page01">
            <fo:region-body region-name="Body"/>
            <fo:region-after region-name="Page01Footer"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>

        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="Page02">
            <fo:region-body region-name="Body"/>
            <fo:region-after region-name="Page02Footer"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>

        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="AllPages">
            <fo:region-body region-name="Body"/>
            <fo:region-after region-name="AllPagesFooter"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>

        <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="PagSeqMaster">
            <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives maximum-repeats="no-limit">
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="Page01"
                                                      page-position="first"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="Page02"
                                                      blank-or-not-blank="blank"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="AllPages"/>
            </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        </fo:page-sequence-master>

        <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="PagSeqMaster-alt">
            <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="Page01"/>
            <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="Page02"/>
            <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives maximum-repeats="no-limit">
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="AllPages"/>
            </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        </fo:page-sequence-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>

    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="PagSeqMaster">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="Page01Footer">
            <fo:block>Footer 01</fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>

        <fo:static-content flow-name="Page02Footer">
            <fo:block>Footer 02  </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:static-content flow-name="AllPagesFooter">
            <fo:block>All Other Pages Footer</fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        
        <fo:flow flow-name="Body">
            <fo:block>
                repeating table content starting on page 1 goes here
            </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Comment: You should state what formatter you are using. It can likely be done with many formatters (but maybe not all) so an answer that points at one specific one is not appropriate.

Comment: I did not give a general answer because every way that I could think of that did not use the AH Formatter extension generated a blank page after a three-page table. If I knew a general answer, I would have provided it.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with AH Formatter by generating a zero-height float on the second page using the `axf:float-move` extension (see https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-float.html#axf.float-move).  The float causes a blank-looking page after a one-page table and doesn't interfere with a two-page or three-page table.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:axf="http://www.antennahouse.com/names/XSL/Extensions">
  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="Page01">
      <fo:region-body region-name="Body"/>
      <fo:region-after region-name="Page01Footer"
               extent="1in" />
    </fo:simple-page-master>

    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="Page02">
      <fo:region-body region-name="Body"/>
      <fo:region-after region-name="Page02Footer"
               extent="1in" />
    </fo:simple-page-master>

    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="AllPages">
      <fo:region-body region-name="Body"/>
      <fo:region-after region-name="AllPagesFooter"
               extent="1in" />
    </fo:simple-page-master>

    <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="TableMaster">
      <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="Page01"/>
      <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="Page02"/>
      <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="AllPages"/>
    </fo:page-sequence-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>

  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="TableMaster">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="Page01Footer">
      <fo:block>Footer 01</fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:static-content flow-name="Page02Footer">
      <fo:block>Footer 02  </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:static-content flow-name="AllPagesFooter">
      <fo:block>All Other Pages Footer</fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    
    <fo:flow flow-name="Body">
      <fo:float float="before" axf:float-move="next"><fo:block/></fo:float>
      <fo:block>
        repeating table content starting on page 1 goes here
      </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>

  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="AllPages">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="AllPagesFooter">
      <fo:block>All Other Pages Footer</fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    
    <fo:flow flow-name="Body">
      <fo:block>
        rest of content goes here
      </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>

  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="TableMaster">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="Page01Footer">
      <fo:block>Footer 01</fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:static-content flow-name="Page02Footer">
      <fo:block>Footer 02  </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:static-content flow-name="AllPagesFooter">
      <fo:block>All Other Pages Footer</fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    
    <fo:flow flow-name="Body">
      <fo:float float="before" axf:float-move="next"><fo:block/></fo:float>
      <fo:block>
        repeating table content starting on page 1 goes here
      </fo:block>
      <fo:block break-before="page">
        repeating table content on page 2 goes here
      </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>

  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="AllPages">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="AllPagesFooter">
      <fo:block>All Other Pages Footer</fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    
    <fo:flow flow-name="Body">
      <fo:block>
        rest of content goes here
      </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>

  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="TableMaster">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="Page01Footer">
      <fo:block>Footer 01</fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:static-content flow-name="Page02Footer">
      <fo:block>Footer 02  </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:static-content flow-name="AllPagesFooter">
      <fo:block>All Other Pages Footer</fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    
    <fo:flow flow-name="Body">
      <fo:float float="before" axf:float-move="next"><fo:block/></fo:float>
      <fo:block>
        repeating table content starting on page 1 goes here
      </fo:block>
      <fo:block break-before="page">
        repeating table content on page 2 goes here
      </fo:block>
      <fo:block break-before="page">
        repeating table content on page 3 goes here
      </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>

  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="AllPages">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="AllPagesFooter">
      <fo:block>All Other Pages Footer</fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    
    <fo:flow flow-name="Body">
      <fo:block>
        rest of content goes here
      </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```